# How can I use Edge in VS Code debugging and make it open private (incognito) window always?

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, microsoft-edge, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger

This is the launch.json

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "msedge",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000/signup",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `"runtimeArgs": ["-inPrivate"],` to your launch configuration.

The docs for `runtimeArgs`: "*Optional arguments passed to the runtime executable.*"

See also [Can Microsoft Edge be launched in “Private Mode” through cmd?](https://superuser.com/q/998488/1749748).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this attribute to you Edge launch configuration:

> "runtimeArgs": ["--inprivate"]

For example:

```
{
  "type": "msedge",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000/signup",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "runtimeArgs": [
   "--inprivate"
 ]
}
```

Hope this help.